# .JSON file in weird characters?

Tags: json

I am trying to edit a savefile for Joe Dever's Lone Wolf HD remastered to test different things but when I opened the .json file, it displays it in weird characters instead of plain text.

Could someone please tell me what encoding it is to display it in plain text?
Here's the file if anyone wants to play around with it:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E_BvdhPbNxOXDCaDLa-qGnRgDy2DJSos/view?usp=sharing

Here is a quick image of it:
[image]

Comment: What's making you think the file is supposed to be JSON? Is the file extension actually `.json`? The titlebar of notepad only names `savegame_000` (with no extension).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, the file extension showed me that it is .json . I tried playing around in Notepad++ to see which languages and encoding combination would give me plain text but to no avail.

Comment: It's likely it's not JSON at all, or that it's encrypted or compressed in some way. Remember that file extensions are ultimately just a luxury for human consumption, they don't really have any bearing on intended type of the file, as manifested in its actual data. I tried using the `file` command to identify it, but it just comes back as "data"

Comment: So I found that the game is written using Unity, so might be in C#. But since opening in notepad doesn't work I guess your assumption that it is encrypted is likely. Unfortunately I have no knowledge on encryption so I might have to drop the ball on this one.

Comment: The game being written in C# tells you nothing at all as to the kind of save file format they use.